# Subset n rows of each level based on the level with fewer rows

Tags: r

Imagine I have some dataframe with a certain number of levels:

```
    x1    x2  ...  xi   Level
1    1     1        1       A    
2    2     2        4       A
3    1     4        2       B
.    .     .        .       B 
.    .     .        .       B
.    .     .        .       C
.    .     .        .       C
.    .     .        .       C
```

I'm trying to subset the dataframe in a way that all levels have n rows, where n is the number of rows of the level with fewer instances. In the example above, A is the less populated level (2 rows), so the desired output is:

```
    x1    x2  ...  xi   Level
1    1     1        1       A    
2    2     2        4       A
3    1     4        2       B
.    .     .        .       B
.    .     .        .       C
.    .     .        .       C
```

The number of levels and rows is variable, so it's necessary to check each time which is the level with fewer rows. In addition, the n rows of each level need to be selected in a (pseudo)random way, in example, if I have:

```
    x1    x2  ...  xi   Level
1    1     1        1       A    
.    .     .        .       .
.    .     .        .       .
.    .     .        .       .
10   1     2        3       C  
11   3     2        1       C  
12   2     1        3       C  
13   3     1        2       C  
14   2     3        1       C
```

and n=3, I would like to avoid choosing the first 3 rows of level C (10,11,12).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` approach with `sample_frac` for randomization:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  add_count(Level) %>%
  mutate(
    n = min(n)
  ) %>%
  group_by(Level) %>%
  sample_frac(1) %>%
  slice(1:n) %>%
  select(-n)
```

Comment: A fraction of `1` is everything.

Comment: Yes, but it permutes the rows so that they are sliced randomly afterwards. Otherwise you only slice the first two rows of the initial dataset.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution uses base R only.

```
n <- min(tapply(Level, Level, length))
inx <- unlist(tapply(seq_along(Level), Level, FUN = function(x) sample(x, n)))
dat[inx, ]
#              x Level
#2   0.414641434     A
#3  -1.539950042     A
#5  -0.294720447     B
#6  -0.005767173     B
#9  -0.799009249     C
#8   0.763593461     C
#14  0.252223448     D
#11 -0.289461574     D
#16  0.435683299     E
#17 -1.237538422     E
```

I have left the row names like this to make it clear that they were not selected consecutively. If, later, you want consecutive row names, do

```
sel <- dat[inx, ]
row.names(sel) <- NULL
```

**Data.**

```
set.seed(1)
s <- sample(2:5, 5, TRUE)
Level <- sapply(1:5, function(i) rep(LETTERS[i], each = s[i]))
Level <- factor(unlist(Level))
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(length(Level)), Level)
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` solution. `dat[, .N, Level]` gives a count of rows for each `Levels` group, then `min(N)` i.e. `minN` is the smallest number of rows. The next line takes the top `minN` rows from each group.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

minN <- dat[, .N, Level][, min(N)]
dat[, head(.SD, minN), Level]

#     Level          x
#  1:     A  1.2724293
#  2:     A  0.4146414
#  3:     B -0.9285670
#  4:     B -0.2947204
#  5:     C  2.4046534
#  6:     C  0.7635935
#  7:     D -0.2894616
#  8:     D -0.2992151
#  9:     E  0.4356833
# 10:     E -1.2375384
```

If you want random rows selected, you can mix `dplyr` and `data.table`

```
library(dplyr) 

dat[, sample_n(.SD, minN), Level]
```

Or use the solution in arg0naut's comment

```
dat[, .SD[sample(.N, minN)], by = Level]
```

If you're willing to sacrifice some readability for speed, another option is

```
dat[dat[, sample(.I, minN), Level]$V1]
```

Data used (from Rui Barradas' answer)

```
set.seed(1)
s <- sample(2:5, 5, TRUE)
Level <- sapply(1:5, function(i) rep(LETTERS[i], each = s[i]))
Level <- factor(unlist(Level))
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(length(Level)), Level)
```

Comment: `minN <- setDT(dat)[, .N, Level][, min(N)]; dat[, .SD[sample(.N, minN)], by = Level]` to make it random.

Answer (score 1):

here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Level) %>%  ## group by level
  mutate(count = n()) %>% ## count number of rows for each group
  ungroup() %>%          
  mutate(count = min(count)) %>%  ## select the minimal number of rows 
  group_by(Level) %>%             ## group again to get X rows for each group
  slice(sample(1:n(), min(count))) %>%    ## get the  X random rows
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-count)             ## remove the added count variable
```

Comment: It works fine, but it selects the n first rows of each level (it should select n rows in a random way), maybe with "createDataPartition()" ? Thanks!

Comment: @Pepv see my answer below, it is a concise version with `sample_frac` for randomization.

Comment: added a `sample`.